# List comprehension for string in Python, using if else condition

Tags: python, string, list, list-comprehension

```
hidden_word = ""
for c in word:
     hidden_word += c if c in guesses else'-'
return hidden_word
```

I'm trying to accomplish this in a single line of code using list comprehension but am having troubles getting an if-else condition to work and think i am missing something. basically if word = 'yes' and guesses contains 'e' then the result should be '-e-'. I'm able to appropriately put the letter but am having trouble with the logic to put the '-' if the letter is not in guesses.

Comment: This should work, what problem are you having?

Comment: `hidden_word = ''.join(c if c in guesses else '-' for c in word)`.

Answer (score 4):

I think your code is fine - it gets the point across. Why use a list comprehension (and then convert that back to a string)?

```
hidden_word = ''.join([c if c in guesses else '-' for c in word])
```

Is that really better? You could change it to a generator expression, but still...

```
hidden_word = ''.join(c if c in guesses else '-' for c in word)
```

**EDIT:** Testing this with a 1000 character "word" using:

```
import timeit
setup = """import random
chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
s = "".join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(1000))
guesses = "agjoxwz"
"""

t1 = "hidden_word = ''.join([c if c in guesses else '-' for c in s])"
t2 = "hidden_word = ''.join(c if c in guesses else '-' for c in s)"
t3 = """hidden_word = ""
for c in s:
     hidden_word += c if c in guesses else '-'"""
```

Results:

```
In [24]: timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt=t1)
Out[24]: 100.88796829901968

In [25]: timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt=t2)
Out[25]: 147.86355467070305

In [26]: timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt=t3)
Out[26]: 247.9441536138757
```

Whoa. So the list comprehension is in fact must faster (and better than a generator expression).

With only 50 letters per "word", the differences are less pronounced, but the list comprehension still wins:

```
In [28]: timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt=t1)
Out[28]: 5.416419290962722

In [29]: timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt=t2)
Out[29]: 7.828715333297168

In [30]: timeit.timeit(setup=setup, stmt=t3)
Out[30]: 7.984714775332918
```

Comment: Using `+`/`+=` for string concatenation in a loop like this can be inefficient if the strings are lengthy. That's one reason to prefer `''join()` on a sequence. Perhaps the strings are short and performance is not an issue, in which case the more readable solution is better.

Comment: @mhawke: I seem to remember that string "adding" has become much more efficient in recent versions of Python, and that `''.join()`'s speed advantage is gone. But I need to test this.

Comment: @mhawke: I was wrong. Adding is in fact much worse on long strings. Thanks!